# normals in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the 1-,2-, and infinity-norms of x = (2, 1, -4, -2) and x = (1+i,
>   1-i, i, 4i).

*Basically I'm having issues with the second set here and I'm trying to figure out how the text arrived at the answers in the back.*

```
    ||x||_1: = |(1+i)+(1-i)+i+4i|=|1+i|+|1-i|+|i|+|4i|=?

    ||x||_2: = sqrt[(1+i)^2+(1-i)^2+i^2+(4i)^2] = sqrt[4+4+1+16] = 5?

    ||x||_infnty: = max {|1+i|, |1-i|, |i|, |4i|} = 4
```

*The answers for the respective problem are 5 + 2sqrt(2), sqrt(21), and 4.*

*Hopefully I haven't overlooked something silly when I approached this problem initially.*

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. 

Proper formatting is expected; for basic information see e.g. [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with $x=(1+i,\,1-i,\,i,\,4i)$, we will have
$$\|x\|_1=\overbrace{|1+i|}^{\sqrt2}\,+\,\overbrace{|1-i|}^{\sqrt2}\,+\,|i|\,+\,|4i| \\
\|x\|_2=\sqrt{|1+i|^2+|1-i|^2+|i|^2+|4i|^2}\\
\|x\|_{\infty}=\max(|1+i|,\,|1-i|,\,|i|,\,|4i|)\,.$$

Comment: _Berci, I don't quite get how you got sqrt of 2 for both 1+i and 1-i. Could you explain that a little for me? Please and thank you!                        EDIT: I think I have figured it out we square the reals and the imaginary when we perform the modulus, right?@Berci_

Comment: Pythagorean theorem. On the complex plane, the distance of $1+i$ from zero (its *absolute value*) is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}$. Also, if you prefer algebraically, we have $|z|^2=z\bar z$, and $z\bar z=(1+i)(1-i)=1-i^2=2$.